# NGXS Devtools doesn't represent the current state

Tags: angular, redux, ngxs

So I started using NGXS and I have some difficulties to inspect my store via Redux Devtools

[NGXS has devtools package](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/plugins/devtools) that integrates with [Redux Devtools Extension](http://extension.remotedev.io/).

I've installed the latest version of the package (^3.2.0) and imported it into `AppModule` imports:

```
imports: [
  NgxsModule.forRoot([ProjectState, AuthState], {developmentMode: true}),
  ...
  NgxsReduxDevtoolsPluginModule.forRoot(),
]
```

On my `AuthState`, I did:

```
export class AuthState implements NgxsOnInit {

    constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}

    ngxsOnInit({dispatch}: StateContext<AuthStateModel>) {
      console.log('State initialized, now getting auth');
      dispatch(CheckAuthSession);
    }

    @Action(CheckAuthSession)
    checkSession({patchState}: StateContext<AuthStateModel>) {
      return this.auth.user$.pipe(
        tap((user) => patchState({initialized: true, user: user})),
      );
    }
```

When I open the console on Google Chrome, I do get the line

```
console.log('State initialized, now getting auth')
```

And the Auth Properties are loaded. Although, on Redux Devtools, I see only:

[image: Redux Devtools]

As you can see:

- The action `CheckAuthSession` isn't dispatched
- `auth.initialized` remains `false` even when I console log it, it's `true`.

The strange thing is that when I dispatch a new action, The extension does mention it and the state changes to what it was **before** the action. I'm not sure if that the correct behavior.

***Update 1***

When I add `take(1)` pipe before the `tap` in `checkSession` method, it somehow works. I have no idea why.

Comment: It could be helpful for you to include the @State definition for your state container class.  Also, typically a dispatch gets a new instance of the action class.

Comment: Will you please share the code of AuthService ?

Comment: @VivekDoshi the `AuthService.user$` returns DocumentReference. The reason I didn't see the current state, was because the subscription wasn't completed. So to keep getting realtime data from the observer AND getting the current state, I had to dispatch and action and then patch the state in the new Action instead of patching an action inside the `tap(..)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason I didn't see my Action on the Devtools was that the action did never end since I didn't subscribe from it. In other words - if you have an action that returns an observable, it won't be displayed on Devtools until the subscription is being complete.

In my example, I didn't want to complete the subscription of my action handler, because I needed to listen to every change of my `user$`.

So to make my code reasonable, I kept the method unsubscribed, but I made a few changes:

- I removed `patchState({initialized: true, user: user})` from `checkSession` because then I wouldn't have any idea if the state has changed since the action won't be displayed because it never ends.
- I added `tap((user) => dispatch(new UpdateAuth(user))` inside the pipe of the `user$` inside the `checkSession` method.
- I created a new method called `onUpdateAuth(user: User)` which being called when `UpdateAuth` action is being triggered

like so:

```
@Action(UpdateAuth)
onUpdateAuth({patchState}: StateContext<AuthStateModel>, {user}: UpdateAuth) {
    patchState({user});
}
```

Took some time to figure it out, but after all - it makes much more sense like that.